# Cochran's Q but for more than two outcomes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, repeated-measures, discrete-data

###### Formal problem

I have a random variable $X$ that takes (unordered) discrete values $i\in [0, 2]\subset\mathbb N$ (there is no order here, I just don't know how to write it neater) that is measured $t \in [0, 3] \subset\mathbb N$ times. I can denote the true pmf. of $X$ as $\rho(t, i)$. Measurements are not independent, i.e., $\text{Cov}[\rho(t_1, i), \rho(t_2,i)] \neq 0$ for any pair $(t_1, t_2)$.

I have an estimator $f(t,i)$ that predicts/approximates $\rho$ (essentially a table of a-priori odds) and a set of $N$ observations of $X$ at different levels of $t$. From these observations I can construct the natural estimator $\hat\rho(t,i) = x_{i,t}/N$ where $x_{i,t}$ denotes the number of times $X$ took the value $i$ at time $t$.

How can I evaluate $f$ in terms of $\hat\rho$?

---

###### Less mathy formulation

Less formally, I have a set of $N=360$ sequences of repeated measurements (repeated $t=4$ times) of a categorical variable with $i=3$ levels. I also have a hypothesized distribution $f$ for these measurements (table of odds), and I want to test this distribution $f$. What is the appropriate test to use?

I know about McNemar's test, but that one only applies to outcomes with two levels (I have more than two). Similar Cochran's Q also needs a binary outcome variable. $\chi^2$ is out as well, due to repeated measurements. This exhausts my knowledge of parameterized tests involving categorical outcomes, so I am curious what I should be doing instead.

---

###### My poor-man's solutions

I thought up two approaches to this problem, but they are courtesy of me and - since I'm actually not a mathematician - come *without warranty of any kind including, but not limited to the warranty of fitness for a particular purpose*. They are likely good for nothing, and I am too naive to see it.

The first test takes a subjectivist approach. I can compute the KL-divergence $D_{KL}(\hat\rho||f)$ and come up with alternative estimators, e.g., a uniform estimator $\hat\rho_\text{uniform}(t,i) = 1/i_\text{max}$, for which I can also compute $D_{KL}$. I can then treat the divergence as a fit index - lower is better - and potentially consider others, e.g. a Gini coefficient. With this I can do a "standard" model comparison. This sounds similar what people in variational inference do (? not sure).

The second test would be to bootstrap the dataset and use this to compute a $.95$-confidence bound for each $\hat\rho(t,i)$. I can then check if $f$ lies within this bound, and if not reject it as a poor estimator.

I can also combine the two, and do a bootstrap to compute the median $D_{KL}(\hat\rho || f)$, which might make the first approach more convincing?

But as I said above, likely both approaches won't do me any good, and I am simply too inexperienced to see it. - As you can see, I feel a little lost and would appreciate guidance.

---

###### Data

As per kjetil's comment, I will try to add more context here as well as the data.

The hypothesized distribution $f$ over levels $i$ of the random variable $X$ at different times $t$ takes the following form.

| $t$ | $t=0$ | $t=2$ | $t=2$ | $t=3$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $i$ |  |  |  |  |
| $i=1$ | .33 | .225 | .25 | .1 |
| $i=2$ | .47 | .55 | .65 | .8 |
| $i=3$ | .2 | .225 | .1 | .1 |

The frequency of occurence of observations at different levels of $t$ looks like this (based on $N=360$ replications):

| $t$ | $t=0$ | $t=2$ | $t=2$ | $t=3$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $i$ |  |  |  |  |
| $i=1$ | 130 | 41 | 105 | 142 |
| $i=2$ | 150 | 253 | 170 | 141 |
| $i=3$ | 80 | 66 | 85 | 77 |

---

###### Background

The data comes from an experiment, where humans (participants) watch a video of a robot going about its business. The objective for participants is to guess the robot's intent. The video is paused $t=4$ times and each time participants are asked to guess the robot's intent by choosing one of $i=3$ multiple-choice options. The true intent is revealed at the end of the video.

I can assume that the data from different participants is iid. Intuitively, you'd think that it matters who watched/rated the video, but - as it turns out - none of the commonly (and not so commonly) assumed confounds show any association with participant's guesses. The only one that seems to matter is level of English language proficiency; presumably, because you don't know what to do if you can't read the instructions. (The data on confounds is so boring, in fact, that I initially thought my plotting scripts were broken.)

The hypothesized distribution $f$ comes from prior work on the topic, i.e., a researcher has derived a clever model of *this is how people's belief evolves when they watch a robot going about its business*. It's a fairly complex model involving the way the robot behaves. At this stage, I treat it like a black box (even though it isn't, it's just kinematics and some non-linear math) and simply look at the output of said model for that one behavior that is shown in the video. This yields my hypothesized distribution $f$.

I'm not sure if I can trust this model (and its implied distribution $f$), so I want to use the data I collected to verify (or reject) the model.

Comment: This would be clearer if you could add an example table, and your hypothesized distribution $f$.  There are no covariables? so it is effectively 360 replications of the rep measurements, under identical conditions?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yes, I can assume that replications of the repeated measurements are under identical conditions. Technically, $f$ has another categorical parameter, but I only consider a single level of it. Also, I have only collected data corresponding to that single level, so - as far as I understand - that should not play a role.

Comment: It would really help if you could edit with that information, and a small example.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Done. Does this improve the question?

Comment: I would try multinomial logistic regression, estimate by maximum likelihood and then compare it via a likelihood ratio test to the model where estimates are restricted by the given (by $f$) probabilities.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for the suggestion! What would my outcome be for the regression? Would I treat sequences $(x_{1,i},\dots,x_{4,i})$ as individual outcomes, because they are assumed to be iid, or would each $x_{t,i}$ be an outcome? If the former, some of the $81$ possible sequences have very low $p$ ($<0.001$, as predicted by $f$), so wouldn't my sample size be too low for this? If the latter, does this still account for the repeated measurements nature of the data?